# MongoDB : Keep only first date

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I'm looking for the easiest and proper solution to reduce/filter an array with mongoDB to get only the first date (and nothing if empty).

Actually, this is my query :

```
$project {
   firstAction:{
      $reduce:{                 
                "input": { $setUnion: ["$fundraisingLog", "$missionLog", "$createdExperiencesLog", "$subscribedExperiencesLog", "$contributionLog"] }, 
                "initialValue":"01.01.2099",
                "in":{

                        $cond:[
                            {
                                $gt:[
                                    {
                                        $dateFromString:{
                                            "dateString":"$$value",
                                            "format":"%d.%m.%Y"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        $dateFromString:{
                                            "dateString":"$$this",
                                            "format":"%d.%m.%Y"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "$$this",
                            "$$value"
                        ]

                }
            }
        }
```

This works almost perfect, expect that if the array

```
$setUnion: ["$fundraisingLog", "$missionLog", "$createdExperiencesLog", "$subscribedExperiencesLog", "$contributionLog"]
```

is empty, I got "01.01.2099" as result instead of null or empty result.

Comment: Ok from your other question & from description of this question - If I get it right, when you say empty result is it 'null' in your above array ? Is that provided is what your aggregation result is, I don't think you'll be able to sort on an array of dates, you can do unwind/convert to date/sort/limit on that array but not sure sort would work properly on that kind of date format !!!! Or you can sort/limit on your date field & then convert it to your string format..

Comment: Why do you've two keys with same name ?

Comment: Which keys have the same name ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your edits : asking about 'firstAction' & 'actionLog' ..

Comment: Yes. I think it's more clear now. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If input array is empty then by default `$reduce` will result in **initialValue**.

If you're not able to do sorting as is with above query or with any other, then I would recommend to try this (this should work on empty) :

**Sample Document :**

```
/* 1 */
{       
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d89113d5a0d22d3c8d2aad0"),
        "actionLog" : [
            "01.01.2014",
            "11.01.2014",
            "09.01.2014",
            "09.09.2014",
            "11.01.2015"
        ]
}
```

**DB query :**

```
db.yourCollection.aggregate([{ $project: { _id: 0 } }, { $unwind: '$actionLog' , preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true },
{ $project: { actionLog: { $dateFromString: { dateString: '$actionLog', format: "%d.%m.%Y" } } } }, { $sort: { actionLog: -1 } }, { $limit: 1 }, {
    $project: {
        actionLog: { $dateToString: { format: "%d.%m.%Y", date: "$actionLog" } }
    }
}])
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "actionLog" : "11.01.2015"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) to find the largest value from the array `uniqueAction`. The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project:{
            "info":{
                $reduce:{
                    "input":"$uniqueAction",
                    "initialValue":{
                        "firstAction":"01.01.1970"
                    },
                    "in":{
                        "firstAction":{
                            $cond:[
                                {
                                    $gt:[
                                        {
                                            $dateFromString:{
                                                "dateString":"$$this",
                                                "format":"%d.%m.%Y"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            $dateFromString:{
                                                "dateString":"$$value.firstAction",
                                                "format":"%d.%m.%Y"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "$$this",
                                "$$value.firstAction"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "uniqueAction" : [
        null,
        "18.08.2018",
        "04.09.2018",
        "05.03.2019",
        "07.08.2019",
        "12.06.2018",
        "13.02.2019",
        "13.03.2019",
        "15.05.2019",
        "15.07.2019",
        "16.08.2018",
        "17.07.2018",
        "18.04.2018",
        "18.06.2019",
        "18.10.2018",
        "21.06.2018",
        "21.09.2019",
        "22.01.2019",
        "22.09.2019",
        "23.07.2019",
        "23.08.2019",
        "24.07.2019",
        "25.06.2019",
        "25.10.2018",
        "26.10.2018",
        "27.06.2019",
        "31.07.2019"
    ]
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d849bfaebcbd560107c54a6"),
    "info" : {
        "firstAction" : "22.09.2019"
    }
}
```

Comment: I try  it but it get me null result :/
Can I do it in the same $project ?

$project : { 
         $setUnion: [ "$uniqueMissions", "$uniqueFundraising", "$uniqueCreatedExperiences", "$uniqueSubscribedExperiences","$uniqueContributions"],       
         },
firstConnexion:{
                $reduce:{...}

 "errmsg" : "an incomplete date/time string has been found, with elements missing: \"01.2019\"",

Comment: @Kaherdin Please share your mongo query